# How can I tell file flush actually works before file close?

Tags: c++, filesystems

I want to make sure data is flushed to disk when I call flush.

A simple code example is:

```
int main() {
    std::ofstream outfile("test.txt");
    for (int n = 0; n < 100; ++n) {
        outfile << n;
        outfile.flush();
        // TODO: insert code to make sure data is flushed to disk
        // I tried using the stat file size but it does not always grow after flush.
    }
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I am sure that `std::ofstream` properly implements the flush function. In fact I am trying test the flush function of another library and this is just an example.

Comment: The `flush` function only flushes the streams buffer. There might be underlying buffers (for example in the operating system or filesystem drivers, or even on the drive itself) that might need to be flushed and synchronized. For this you need to consult the documentation for your operating system.

Comment: out of curiosity: why call `flush` at all ? I wouldnt want to flush the file inside the loop

Comment: @idclev463035818 this is just an example for testing `flush`. Not intended to be used in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`outfile.flush()` will flush the stream buffer to the operating system. If you want to make sure the system buffers are flushed to disk, you must issue an OS specific system call to do that. On POSIX compliant systems, you can call [`sync()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sync) defined in `<unistd.h>`.